# Does onCreateOptionsMenu pass a menu to onOptionsItemSelected?

Tags: android

Ive inflated a menu in onCreateOptionsMenu and handled functionality in onOptionsItemSelected but I was just wondering, what passes the inflated menu to onOptionsItemSelected. I'm thinking onCreateOptionsMenu but I'm not sure.

Comment: The items in the Menu is passed to the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item). So the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) is first called and then the Menu item is then passed to onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

Answer (score 0):

The first time a menu is needed by Android for a particular instance of an Activity, it will call onCreateOptionsMenu().  The Menu and all of its MenuItem objects that you create and return there will be remembered for as long as that activity is active, and reused for subsequent calls to onPrepareOptionsMenu() and onOptionsItemSelected().  All of these objects will go away when the activity instance is destroyed, and new ones will be created for new instances of the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

try to do in onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
    }
```

and in onOptionsItemSelected

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
```

Using item as menu